# How many pair combinations for a string of given length N

Tags: string, combinatorics

Given a string N, how many paired combinations(meaning - a group of 2 elements) i can make out of that string.
Can we derive a general formula to find no of pair elements ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please don't expect us to make your homework, you have to tell us what have you done so far and post some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If order doesn't matter (in other words, if the string was OTHER, ET is equivalent to TE) then you just use the Choose function, which is defined as Ch(n, k) (pronounced n choose k) = n!/(k! * (n-k)!);  In this case, there would be Ch(5,2) = 120/12 = 10 combinations, which can be demonstrated by inspection:
OT, OH, OE, OR, TH, TE, TR, HE, HR, ER

Assuming this is homework, I'd encourage plenty of practice on this topic- the nuances of combinatorics are pretty subtle and extremely useful once you get the hang of it.